# ASP.NET repeater only renders the first item in my XML data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, repeater, xmldatasource

I have an XML Data Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
    <items>
        <item id="1" text="X" />
        <item id="2" text="Y" />
        <item id="3" text="Z" />
    </items>
</Data>
```

In my page I have wired this up to an `asp:XmlDataSource`:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" ID="data" DataFile="~/items.xml" />
```

And bound this to an `asp:Repeater`:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="list" DataSourceID="data">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li data-id="<%# XPath("item/@id") %>"><%# XPath("item/@text") %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I am only getting the first item in the items list. How do I get them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add an `XPath="/Data/items/item"' attribute to your XmlDataSource, then change the li elements in the ItemTemplate to:

```
<li data-id="<%# XPath("@id") %>"><%# XPath("@text") %></li>
```